# Collaborative Ruby resources for novices

Tags: ruby

I am very much a Ruby newb - hoping to migrate to Ruby on Rails (although I have walked through Mike Hartl's Tutorial, which was excellent).  I just want to solidify my Ruby knowledge first.

I am working on a hobby Ruby project to help me learn. I am pretty happy with how far I have got so far, but wanted to discuss/share it with other like-minded novice/beginner programmers.

**Can anyone point me to a 'community' that promotes collaboration, critisim and discussion on code (ideally Ruby, obvs)?**

**If such a community doesn't exist, does anyone have any advice on how to find other like-minded programmers working on small-scale scripts/programs?**

I have an account on Github, and on here (obviously!).  Whilst Github is great for navigating around, cloning and looking at people's code, I don't feel anywhere near the level where I can start to actually contribute to anything and likewise request people look at my code.  Maybe I am just being a wuss and I should just jump in the deep end?  Perhaps I am not using GitHub correctly as a 'social network'.

Also, from what I can see, StackOverflow is not the place to send out 'Hey, check this out and let me know what you think' type requests either.

Not meant to be a discussion - just whether anyone knows if such 'networks' exist.

Comment: reddit.com/r/ruby and r/rails are the only places I can think of even remotely relevant to what you proposed. Not exactly bustling with activity, but I've met some collaborators and successfully pitched "Can I get some feedback on this code?"-type questions on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you're located, but hacknights (Ruby or otherwise) are probably up your alley. There are different flavors (Are you solving a stated problem? Working on something general?) but usually you can work with others in a collaborative and low-stakes environment. I'd suggest searching for "hacknight" in your area and look at any past or upcoming nights.

As an example, see http://www.meetup.com/torontoruby/events/53887372/

Comment: That is very interesting - and it does look like there is one in my area, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) - very interesting project for knowing ruby-technologies.

Also you can going to software-company and start working, and you get criticism, discussions and collaboration :)

Comment: haha - maybe one day.  I think perhaps the fact I have followed a tutorial in Rails isn't quite the level of experience most software development companies are looking fore...